# How to edit an image in Gimp when the target display has different horoiztonal and vertical resolution?

Tags: image, gimp

I want to make a wallpaper for this desktop, which has a resolution of 1024 x 384
[image]

When I create an image of this dimension in GIMP, it looks like it's half the height by comparison:
[image]

It's difficult to create art at a different ratio to the target. How can I handle this in GIMP? (I'm told that in photoshop there is a menu option for this situation, so they look the same but still have the same dimensions but I don't know what it's called.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `Image ➤ Print size` you can set a different vertical and horizontal resolution for the image (click the chain link to decouple them). You typically want an Y resolution which is half the X one, and best use a resolution which is close to your actual display, possibly 100PPI for X and 50PPI for Y).
- Tell Gimp you want it to work using the print size: un-tick `View ➤ Dot for dot`

Remember that Gimp still works with pixels, if you copy/paste a square from another image, it will be stretched vertically. Likewise a 1:1 aspect ration in the Rectangle and Ellipse selection tools will yield a vertically stretched selection.
On the other hand if you create text with the text tool, it will look normal in "Print size" view, and stretched horizontally in "Dot for Dot" view.

Comment: Thank you. The result is perfect! I would never have figured that out.

Comment: Also, if there is a suggestion for a better title to the question for search engines, it would be good to help other people find it.

Comment: How about "How to edit an image in Gimp when the target display has different horoiztonal and vertical resolution? (though technically this question isn't much about programming and would have been better asked on [GraphicDesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gimp) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gimp)).

Comment: Updated, thank you. Ah, I didn't realise there was a better place to put this. Noted.